# How to compare 2 hours from dateTime flutter

Tags: string, datetime, flutter

Im getting an error saying i have wrong hour format when my hour format is 17:30:00 when comparing it to another hour, both my hour here is the code:

```
  if (DateTime.parse(hourTempEnd)
          .isBefore(DateTime.parse(hourTempStart))) {
      }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does your string include a date as well as a time? Date is required for parsing: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: No it does not, it only contains the hours, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime x = DateTime.Now;

DateTime y = Convert.ToDateTime("10:00:00 AM");

int i = DateTime.Compare(x,y);`

I think instead of using DateTime.Parse you should try to use Convert.ToDateTime

Came across some examples like that over here

https://forums.asp.net/t/1025431.aspx?How+to+compare+Time+in+C+

Comment: Thank you it worked with some small modifications for flutter :)

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, use this DateTime method to obtain a Duration object:

```
 Duration DateTime.difference(DateTime)
```

Use it would be:

```
 Duration duration = dateTime1.difference(dateTime2);
 print(duration.inHours().toString());
```